# Create textbox dynamically without postback

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, updatepanel, postback

I would like to have a button which onclick  would dynamically create a textbox without any postback. I was trying to do it using the update panel but till now I have not managed to do it. Nothing  is created on button click. The following is the code I have used:

```
 <asp:PlaceHolder ID="textboxes" runat="server"/>

     <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptMgr" runat="server" />
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePnl" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div>
                            <asp:Button id="Button" text="Add Destination" OnClick="btnCreate_Click" runat="server"/>
                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

CODEBEHIND

```
  protected void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             textboxes.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { ID = "txt" + 1 });

        }
```

This is what I get on aler(container);:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use OnClientClick for creating textbox without postback

```
<asp:Button id="Button" text="Add Destination" OnClientClick="return CreateTxt(); runat="server"/>

<script type="text/javascript">


function CreateTxt()
{
    var container = document.getElementById("myContainerDiv");
    var html = document.getElementById('myContainerDiv').innerHTML;
    html = html + "<input type=text ... /><br />";
    container.innerHTML= html;
   return false;
}

</script>
```

myContainerDiv is the name of div where you want to add textbox.

Comment: still no textbox has been created and it does a postback also @Aarif

Comment: I have posted the result of the alert in my question @Aarif

Comment: Still no textbox is being created. @Aarif

Comment: it works in my code,just past same JavaScript function and onclientclick event of button ,

Comment: i replaced innerHtml with innerHTML in function

Comment: iT WORKED now. The innerHTML was the problem. BUT only one textbox let me create? @Aarif

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail how to accomplish the multiple textbox issue? @Aarif

Comment: Please change 2nd line to this for multiple textbox                var html = document.getElementById('myContainerDiv').innerHTML;

Comment: Thanks very much :). It works. By any chance is it possible to get the value of each textbox?

Comment: some how you have to generate textbox with ids or names,and from ids of textbox you can find value of that

Answer (score 2):

Use this inside Button click event.

```
    TextBox t = new TextBox();
    t.ID = "txt";
    this.form1.Controls.Add(t);
```

you can add as many textboxes u want using this..But when postback occurs they are difficult to manage.Refer the below links to know more about dynamic controls and postbacks..

1.[Dynamic Web Server Controls and View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbdfdyh7.aspx)

2.[Dynamic Web Controls, Postbacks, and View State](https://web.archive.org/web/20211031102347/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx)

Comment: I need to give the user the facility to create as many textboxes as he wants amd then I will get the values of the textboxes @coder

Comment: @IT_info by using dynamic controls its difficult to avoid postback.

Comment: Is there a better way of doing it in order not to have postback on the creation of textbox? @coder

Comment: I have updated my answer check it @IT_info..Refer those links u will understand better.

Answer (score 0):

I think in Javascript , you can use like this. Hope this helps you...

```
var element = document.createElement("jsTextBox");
```

//Assign different attributes to the element.

```
    element.setAttribute("value", "text");
<SpanElement>.appendChild(element);
```